# Classic ASP: Trying to show a time stored in a "(time(0) , NULL) sql server field

Tags: sql-server, time, asp-classic, fieldtype

I'm storing a time value (for example 18:30 - Spain format) in a `sql-server` 2014 Database from a classic asp web application. The field (dtHoraInicio) is defined as (time(0), NULL). The inserts work and the data is stored well.

In my web page I'm just trying to show the value:

```
response.write oRSC("dtHoraInicio") 'where oRSC is the recordset
```

and I get this error:

> Microsoft Cursor Engine error '80020009'
>
> Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value

I changed the way to access the data returned to this:

```vbs
Conexion = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=xxxxxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=yyyyyyyy;User Id=zzzzzzzz;Password=aaaaaaaaaaa"

Set objConexion = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConexion.CommandTimeout=120
objConexion.ConnectionTimeOut = 120
objConexion.Open Conexion

Set oRSC=CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oRSC.ActiveConnection = objConexion
oRSC.CursorType = 0 ' 1 adOpenKeyset
oRSC.CursorLocation = 3 'adUseClient
oRSC.LockType = 3 'adLockOptimistic
oRSC.Source = FiltrarCadena(ssqlC)
oRSC.Open

'------------------------
response.write oRSC("dtHoraInicio")
'------------------------
```

And I got this new error:

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bb9'
>
> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

If I try to execute it in local/testing environment, it works perfect, also connecting from local to the production database is fine, but in the moment I upload the file to production, the code fails. So I don't know if it's a problem of the code or if comes from the database configuration.

If I execute the query in `sql-server` Management Studio it runs perfect and shows all the data without problems.

Any idea?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Sorry, the connection used in production is: "Driver={SQL Server};Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;xxxxxxxxxxx;database=xxxxxxxx;uid=xxxxxxxx;pwd=xxxxxxxx"  and from local I'm connecting without provider and it works, but the IT team tells me they cannot change the way of connection, so my question is why the Time filed type is not recognized with OLEDB? thank you

Comment: We got it, finally we converted the time field to varchar in the query before show it on the page. You can delete this question if you want (I didn't find the way) or leave it, maybe it's usefull for someone. Regards.

Comment: That is valid question and answer, please post the solution as self answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(5), TIME) as TIME from <table>
```

Where "TIME" is (time(0) null) type field and I convert to varchar(5) because in Spain the time format is hh:mm